# MySQL show all months In between date

Tags: mysql, date, between

i, have query

```
select 
       CONCAT(monthname(a.tanggal), ' ', year(a.tanggal)) as bulan_tahun, 
       sum(a.kg) as kg, 
       sum(a.ka) as ka, 
       sum(a.lr) as lr, 
       sum(a.lh) as lh, 
       sum(a.lb) as lb, 
       sum(a.ll) as ll, 
       sum(a.nc) as nc, 
       sum(a.na) as na, 
       sum(a.sbs) as sbs, 
       sum(a.stbs) as stbs, 
       sum(a.kg)+sum(a.ka)+sum(a.lr)+sum(a.lh)+sum(a.sbs)+sum(a.lb)+sum(a.ll)+sum(a.nc)+sum(a.na)+sum(a.stbs) as total 
   from 
      opr.t_temuan as a 
   where 
          a.id_site=197 
      and a.tanggal between '2010-02-01' and '2011-01-31' 
      and (a.type ='f' or a.type = 'i') 
   group by 
      bulan_tahun 
   order by 
      a.tanggal asc
```

i get return month

```
June 2010 0 0 5 0 4 6 0 0 3 3 21
July 2010 0 0 99 39 4 4 0 0 2 2 150
August 2010 0 0 62 79 0 5 5 0 0 0 151
September 2010 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
November 2010 0 0 59 4 75 1 0 0 8 8 155
December 2010 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

but i want return month start january 2010 to december 2010
like this

```
January 2010 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Febuary 2010 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Marc 2010 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
April 2010 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
May 2010 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
June 2010 0 0 5 0 4 6 0 0 3 3 21
July 2010 0 0 99 39 4 4 0 0 2 2 150
August 2010 0 0 62 79 0 5 5 0 0 0 151
September 2010 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
November 2010 0 0 59 4 75 1 0 0 8 8 155
December 2010 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

please help me !!
thanks

Comment: if you do not have data for those months in your database, then it will not come in your output

Answer (score 0):

The first query uses variables joined with ANY table and limiting to 12 months just so it will auto-generate each month/year you want... ex: starting with 2010-01-01 and going for 12 months.  The second query is almost identical to your original, pre-grouping by months that have actual data.  Then, by left-joining them, each month in the first will grab what it can find in the final data aggregations, but keep the results based on the date and not alphabetically.

```
select 
      date_format(justDates.FirstOfMonth,'%M %Y') ShowDate,
      ifnull(PreSummary.kg, 0) as kg,
      ifnull(PreSummary.ka, 0) as ka,
      ifnull(PreSummary.lr, 0) as lr,
      ifnull(PreSummary.lh, 0) as lh,
      ifnull(PreSummary.lb, 0) as lb,
      ifnull(PreSummary.ll, 0) as ll,
      ifnull(PreSummary.nc, 0) as nc,
      ifnull(PreSummary.na, 0) as na,
      ifnull(PreSummary.sbs, 0) as sbs,
      ifnull(PreSummary.stbs, 0) as stbs,
      ifnull(PreSummary.total, 0) as Total
   from
      ( SELECT @dt:= date_add( @dt, interval 1 month ) FirstOfMonth
          FROM (select @dt := '2010-01-01' ) vars,
               opr.t_temuan
               LIMIT 12 ) JustDates
      left join 
      ( Select 
              date_format(a.tanggal,'%M %Y') ShowDate,
              sum(a.kg) as kg,
              sum(a.ka) as ka,
              sum(a.lr) as lr,
              sum(a.lh) as lh,
              sum(a.lb) as lb,
              sum(a.ll) as ll,
              sum(a.nc) as nc,
              sum(a.na) as na,
              sum(a.sbs) as sbs,
              sum(a.stbs) as stbs,
              sum(a.kg+a.ka+a.lr+a.lh+a.sbs+a.lb+a.ll+a.nc+a.na+a.stbs) as total
         from 
            opr.t_temuan as a
         where
                a.id_site=197
            and a.tanggal between '2010-02-01' and '2011-01-31'
            and a.type in ( 'f', 'i')
         group by
             1 ) PreSummary
      on JustDates.ShowDate = PreSummary.ShowDate
  order by
      JustDates.FirstOfMonth
```